# Expose a function to the script added using "page.addScriptTag" Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have some simple code that executes a script and takes a screenshot.

```
const browser = await launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto("www.google.com");
await page.addScriptTag({ content: "myScript" });

await page.screenshot({
  path: "myPath",
  fullPage: false,
});
```

Now, I want to exposes a take screenshot function to the script. For example

```js
// code in script
takeScreenshot(myArg);
```

The function will be something like this.

```js
function takeScreenshot(name) {
  // Save it somewhere in file system
  await page.screenshot({
    path: `path/${name}`,
    fullPage: false,
  });
}
```

That's not all, there's a catch:

The `takeScreenshot` function also needs access to some other variables which may/may not be in the same scope. Here's an example of the full code.

```js
const someRoute = (req, res) => {
  const var1 = '';
  const var2 = '';

  const browser = await launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("www.google.com");
  await page.addScriptTag({ content: "myScript" });

  await page.screenshot({
    path: "myPath",
    fullPage: false,
  });

  function takeScreenshot(name) {
    // Save it somewhere in file system
    await page.screenshot({
      path: `SOMEPATH/${var1}/${var2}/${name}`,
      fullPage: false,
    });
  }
}
```

I think that we should attach the `takeScreenshot` function to the `window` object so the script can call that as `window.takeScreenshot()`. Here are the issues:

1. How to attach `takeScreenshot()` to the window
2. How to make sure that `takeScreenshot` has access to the variables `var1` and `var2`?

THanks in advance guys!

Comment: This seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) on a couple of levels. Firstly, you can't attach a Node function that accesses a page object to the browser's window. Anything you want to pass to browser context must be serializable, typically simple primitive data like array of strings, not core Puppeteer objects. Secondly, it seems strange to want to access variables dynamically outside of a function. Functions should be self-contained black boxes that don't rely on external state. Generally, you'd use parameters.

Comment: If you don't mind explaining what you're really trying to accomplish with all of these machinations, I might be able to offer a more sensible approach.

Comment: It seems [`page.exposeFunction()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) can help here.

Comment: All i'm trying to do is that when a user sends a request to my api with a url and script, Go to the url, execute the script and save the screenshot in the filesystem. I also want to expose a takeScreenshot function that can be used inside the script to take a screenshot and save that. The function will take some arguments regarding the path to decide where to place the image